# Is there a way to compute correlations by row (or a dataframe of rows ) in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, pearson-correlation

I have a data set that looks like

```
              P.Expression   Selumetnib Trametinib PD0325901 Refametinib PD184352  MEK162   AZD8330
PPP21RA       -0.096191870  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R1B       -0.064184226  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R2A       -0.128419157  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R2B       -0.063257953  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R2D       -0.032955238  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R3A        0.011361271  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R3B       -0.062511061  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R3C        0.020991054  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R4        -0.072609674  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R5A       -0.059546070  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R5B       -0.028235984  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R5C       -0.066032773  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R5D       -0.115840827  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2R5E       -0.076210841  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2CA        -0.048093574  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPP2CB         0.077807157  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
LCMT1         -0.231211557  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
LCMT2         -0.062586132  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.3759267
PPME1         -0.005757402  0.8246568  0.7194128 0.8585802   0.6980149 0.693675 0.510329 0.375926
```

I'm interested in finding the correlation of each protein expression between each drug so PPP21RA expression (-0.096191870) against the other columns.

I tried

```
cor.test(KrasHeat[1,1], KrasHeat[1,2], method = "pearson")
Error in cor.test.default(KrasHeat[1, 1], KrasHeat[1, 2:7], method = "pearson") : 
  not enough finite observations
```

But this down not work.

I also tried applying cor.test to the entire data frame but I end up with a value that cannot be broken down by the specific proteins

Is there a way to do this?

I'm also wondering if it's possible to graphically represent this in a correlation matrix or heatmap.

Comment: I am not sure I understood. Are you trying to do `cor(df[1,],df[2,])`, `cor(df[1,],df[3,])`...? If you want correlation matrix, you can have a look at `corrplot` package

Comment: I think you need a matrix which is done by several packages eg `corrplot` mentioned above. `get_var_corr_` from [manymodelr](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/master/R) that I wrote also supports this. You may also look at `broom`.

Comment: The data is already in matrix format. I really just want ```cor(df[1,1], df[1,2 (or 3, 4, 5, etc.)]``` for each protein in the matrix. A correlation matrix just compares expression values to one another and i don't want that. i want the expression values correlated to the drug sensitivity values.